# I have a list of tuples and need to drop each one that has integer values that overlaps other tuple

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples

I have a list of tuples, inside each tuple there are two integers and a string.
I need to generate a new list that drops the tuples where their integers range are overlapped inside other tuple.

I tried with this:

```
list_all = [(0, 3, 'textA'), (0, 5, 'textB'), (8, 11, 'textC')]

empty_list = []

for i in list_all:
  range_i = list( range(list_all[i][0], list_all[i][1]) )
  
  for j in list_all:
    range_j = list( range(list_all[j][0], list_all[j][1]) )
    
    if  all( item in range_j for item in range_i ) == False:
      empty_list.append(range_i)

empty_list
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-233-b4cebb65d49c> in <module>()
      4 
      5 for i in list_all:
----> 6   range_i = list( range(list_all[i][0], list_all[i][1]) )
      7 
      8   for j in list_all:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to only keep the tuple with the largest range when it has overlapping range with other tuples. You can use set comparison operator `<` to check if a range is inside another range. Note that `set(a) < set(b)` effectively means `set(a)` is a subset of `set(b)` and not equal to `set(b)`.

Here is an one-line code for your question:

```
list_all = [(0, 3, 'textA'), (0, 5, 'textB'), (8, 11, 'textC')]

res = [t for t in list_all if not any(set((range(t[0], t[1]))) < set(r)
       for r in [range(i, j) for (i, j, _) in list_all])]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 5, 'textB'), (8, 11, 'textC')]
```

The idea is to first get all the ranges, and select only the tuples that have a range set not less than any other tuple range sets.

Of course you can also write it as

```
res = [t for t in list_all if all(set((range(t[0], t[1]))) > set(r)
       for r in [range(i, j) for (i, j, _) in list_all])]
```

Comment: @ignaciobaldriz You can consider to accept the answer if it works great for you

Comment: How would you solve if the input were: 

`
list_all = [(0, 3, 'textA'), 
                 (0, 5, 'textB'),
                 (6, 8, 'textB'), 
                 (6, 8, 'textC'),
                 (8, 12, 'textC'), 
                 (10, 25, 'textD'),
                 (30, 35, 'textD'),
                 (30, 35, 'textD')
               ]

And the expected utput:

`
list_all = [(0, 5, 'textB'),
                 (6, 8, 'textB'),  ​
                ​(10, 25, 'textD'),
                ​(30, 35, 'textD'),
                ​(30, 35, 'textD')
              ​]
`

Comment: Notice that now is included a different kind of overlap: (8, 12, 'textC') (10, 25, 'textD'). Where (8, 12, 'textC') is dropped because it has a shorter range. 

Also is supposed to drop full overlaps between different categories: (6, 8, 'textB') (6, 8, 'textC') keeping the first one. But not drop them if the string part of the tuples are the same: (30, 35, 'textD') (30, 35, 'textD).

Comment: @ignaciobaldriz First of all, you are now asking a completely different question and you should post another question for it. Regarding the new "restrictions" you mentioned, I don't quite understand why ``(8, 12, 'textC')`` should be dropped. If it should be dropped due to shorter range, then why isn't ``(6, 8, 'textB')`` dropped? What I understood is to drop tuples with range *insde* another range, so you should not compare ``range(8, 12)`` with ``range(10, 25)`` directly, unless you just want to compare the length. Then again, it is way too confusing with all your "restrictions".

Comment: Okay, don't worry I would post then a new question. This is my first post on the site sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because `i` points to a tuple, not an index (since you wrote `for i in list_all:` not `for i in range(len(list_all))`

As for the task at hand, do you want to keep only the intervals that don't overlap with anything or do you want to keep a list of the maximum number of intervals that don't overlap? For example, if there are 3 ranges A,B,C where A and C overlap with B but A don't overlap with C, do you want to return [A,C] or []?

Comment: Okay, thanks that solved what I posted. But your answer lead me to understand that the output I was looking for was quite different. Let me re answer below

Comment: @ignaciobaldriz Based on your updated post, if now the only problem is there are duplicated results then you can just add another line in the end:

`empty_list = set(empty_list)`

which would get rid of the overlapped tuples. 
If you want the ranges to maintain ascending order in terms of the starting point of the range, you can also add:

`empty_list = sorted(list(empty_list), key=lambda x: x[0])`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed version of my code (thanks Eric Cartman). I realised that what I needed was a list without ex. (0, 3, 'textA'), because 0-3 overlaps with 0-5.

```
list_all = [(0, 3, 'textA'), (0, 5, 'textB'), (8, 11, 'textC'), (20, 25, 'textD')]

empty_list = []

for i in range(len(list_all)):
  range_i = list( range(list_all[i][0], list_all[i][1]) )
  
  for j in range(len(list_all)):
    range_j = list( range(list_all[j][0], list_all[j][1]) )
    
    if  all( item in range_j for item in range_i ) == False:
      empty_list.append(list_all[i])


empty_list
```

I have this output, I almost have it, but I'm generating duplicates:

```
'''
[(0, 3, 'textA'),
 (0, 3, 'textA'),
 (0, 5, 'textB'),
 (0, 5, 'textB'),
 (0, 5, 'textB'),
 (8, 11, 'textC'),
 (8, 11, 'textC'),
 (8, 11, 'textC'),
 (20, 25, 'textD'),
 (20, 25, 'textD'),
 (20, 25, 'textD')]
'''
```